# Why does ("str" + x == y) only compile for reference types?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, equality

Why does == operator behave differently with references than with primitive data types?.

```
String string1 = "myString";
String string2 = "myString";
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 10;
System.out.println("Value is "+string1==string2);   //WORKS FINE 
System.out.println("Value is "+num1==num2);         //COMPILE TIME ERROR
```

I am unable to figure out any logical reason behind this.
PS: Brackets inside the print statements are deliberately not used.
Thanks :)

Comment: It makes sense if you think of the `==` operator comparing the values of the references. So in all cases, the `==` operator compares the values of its operands. Also, what you have there is an order of operations problem, not a problem with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 10):

It's an issue of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). Your second print statement is being interpreted as:

```
System.out.println(("Value is "+num1)==num2);  // notice the parenthesis
```

which attempts to compare a string with an int, producing a compile-time error. Add parenthesis to solve the problem:

```
System.out.println("Value is " + (num1==num2));  // compiles
```

The precedence of Java operators is outlined in [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Now, this:

```
// original:
System.out.println("Value is "+string1==string2);

// equivalent to:
System.out.println(("Value is "+string1)==string2);
```

works because `"Value is "+string1` is a string itself, so it's valid to compare it to `string2` with `==`.

Comment: Hi @arshajii. I verified this by trying to use `System.out.println("Value is "+string1==string1)`. My previous knowledge said that this would output true, but it prints out false as explained by your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the `operator precedence` you cant compare string to int.

**problem 1:**

```
System.out.println("Value is "+num1==num2);
```

`+` sign has higher precedence than `==` so it will execute `+` first and then `==` is executed

So after `+` is executed this is the **result**:

```
 System.out.println("Value is 10"==num2);  //num1 is appended to the string
```

**problem 2:**

```
"Value is 10"==num2
```

that is where the compile error is coming, string cant be compared to int.

**solution:**

if you want to compare int first you need to wrap it inside the parenthesis to avoid compile time error

```
System.out.println("Value is "+ (num1==num2));
```